# Get character ID based on mouse cursor for TEdit

Tags: delphi

I posted a previous question based on a child form. Without the child form, the caret is where you click on the TEdit.
Using the following code I can get focus on the TEdit and the caret at the end of the text:

```
edt2.SetFocus;
edt2.SelStart := Length(edt2.Text);
```

This is 99% of what I want to do.
I found code that can get the position of the mouse cursor and it works perfectly on a TRichEdit, however it does not work on a TEdit (or TMemo). I wrote it for the MouseDown on the TEdit. As a test I copied it to the MouseMove. In both instances the only result I get is -1

```
procedure TfrmClientManager.edt1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState;
  X, Y: Integer);
var
  iCharIndex: Integer;
  Pt: TPoint;
begin
  with TEdit(Sender) do
  begin
    Pt := Point(X, Y);
    // Get Character Index from word under the cursor
    iCharIndex := Perform(Messages.EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, Integer(@Pt));
    Caption := IntToStr(iCharIndex);
  end;
```

**EDIT:**
Fixed typing mistake with the SetFocus.

**EDIT:**
As per Remy Lebeau the following below works 100%

```
edt2.SetFocus;
edt2.SelStart := LOWORD(TEdit(Sender).Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MAKELPARAM(X, Y)));
```

Comment: On a side note: for your 1st snippet, `TEdit.SetFocus()` is a method, not a property. You can't assign a value to it. Also, `TEdit.GetTextLen()` is more efficient than using `Length(TEdit.Text)`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau you are correct regarding SetFocus. My mistake when typing it initially - that is what I meant.
What does GetTextLength do different?

Comment: @Remy Lebeau that is EXACTLY what I needed. I came across very similar code, but for Pascal. Just could not get it to work. This allows me to have a child form and be able to correctly focus and set the caret for the TEdit.

Comment: "*What does GetTextLength do different?*" - an Edit control always knows how many characters it has. `GetTextLen()` simply queries that value (via [`WM_GETTEXTLENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-gettextlength)). Reading the `Text` property has to allocate memory for a new `String` and copy the characters into it, which is needless overhead when you just want the length.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau thanks for that lesson between the two. Will remember that in the future.

Answer (score 3):

`EM_CHARFROMPOS` works just fine with `TEdit`. But, if you read its [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-charfrompos), you will see that its input and return value are very different for a RichEdit control vs an Edit control:

> ### Parameters
>
> *wParam*
>
> This parameter is not used.
>
> *lParam*
>
> The coordinates of a point in the control's client area. The coordinates are in screen units and are relative to the upper-left corner of the control's client area.
>
> **Rich edit controls:** A pointer to a `POINTL` structure that contains the horizontal and vertical coordinates.
>
> **Edit controls:** The `LOWORD` contains the horizontal coordinate. The `HIWORD` contains the vertical coordinate.
>
> ### Return value
>
> **Rich edit controls:** The return value specifies the zero-based character index of the character nearest the specified point. The return value indicates the last character in the edit control if the specified point is beyond the last character in the control.
>
> **Edit controls:** The `LOWORD` specifies the zero-based index of the character nearest the specified point. This index is relative to the beginning of the control, not the beginning of the line. If the specified point is beyond the last character in the edit control, the return value indicates the last character in the control. The `HIWORD` specifies the zero-based index of the line that contains the character. For single-line edit controls, this value is zero. The index indicates the line delimiter if the specified point is beyond the last visible character in a line.

The code you have shown is suited for a RichEdit control, not an Edit control.

Try this instead:

```pascal
procedure TfrmClientManager.edt1MouseMove(Sender: TObject;
  Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Integer);
var
  iCharIndex: Integer;
begin
  // Get Character Index from word under the cursor
  iCharIndex := LOWORD(TEdit(Sender).Perform(EM_CHARFROMPOS, 0, MAKELPARAM(X, Y)));
  Caption := IntToStr(iCharIndex);
end;
```